# VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Mouse Click cursor misplaced

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, user-interface, testing

I'm trying to execute the UI test cases from my project (this is testing a web site), and they are calling several times:

```
Mouse.Click(UITestControl, Point);
```

I also tried calling:

```
Mouse.Click(UITestControl);
```

Everything is  working fine in a couple of other devs machines, but in mine it seems to be some offset in the coordinates, the cursor is not moving to the right position of the controls is supposed to click on, has anybody else dealt with this kind of issue? Is there some configuration that can be used to make the click points more generic?

Comment: do you have any more info about *how* it's misplaced? is it off to one side all the time? or is it inconsistent?

Comment: Seems like is going to the same wrong place all the times.